# Playframework migration to 2.3.9 is missing play-docs and blocks startDevMode

Tags: migration, playframework-2.3

After migration from playframework-2.2.4 to playframework-2.3.9 I get the following error on run:

```
[namek] $ run

java.util.NoSuchElementException: head of empty list
        at scala.collection.immutable.Nil$.head(List.scala:337)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Nil$.head(List.scala:334)
        at play.runsupport.Reloader$.startDevMode(Reloader.scala:184)
        at play.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.devModeServer$lzycompute$1(PlayRun.scala:75)
        at play.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.play$PlayRun$class$$anonfun$$anonfun$$anonfun$$devModeServer$1(PlayRun.scala:75)
        at play.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(PlayRun.scala:98)
        at play.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(PlayRun.scala:54)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) java.util.NoSuchElementException: head of empty list
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed 26-May-2015 12:35:03
```

In the source file Reloader.scala:184 (https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.9/framework/src/run-support/src/main/scala/play/runsupport/Reloader.scala) I see a reference to "play-docs" in the name of docsClasspath: Classpath received as a parameter in startDevMode.

```
val docsJarFile = {
        val f = docsClasspath.filter(_.getName.startsWith("play-docs")).head
        new JarFile(f)
      }
```

What should I do? I couldn't find any reference on this play-docs name.

---

UPDATE
    It seems that in an old version playDocsJar used a headOption and not a head (https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/848329be7d8a2d3d52d9031880332d46f845899e/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/play/sbt/PlaySettings.scala)

```
playDocsJar := (managedClasspath in DocsApplication).value.files.filter(_.getName.startsWith(playDocsName.value)).headOption,
```

Answer (score 0):

As a **workaround** I created a DocsApplication and added a dummy library

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-docs" % play.core.PlayVersion.current % "docs"
```